# ProFtpd give user full access over sftp

Tags: vpn, ftp, webmin, proftpd

Im using WebMin on my VPS server for several years. Now I want to create different FTP users with locked access to their home folder. Everything working fine, but ProFtpd giv each user full acces when connect via SFTP instead of normal FTP

What should I do?

Comment: Despite its name, SFTP is entirely unrelated to FTP, and, as such, ProFTPd.

Comment: ... but apparently ProFTPDd [can be configured as an SFTP server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-proftpd-to-use-sftp-instead-of-ftp). This looks like something that would be helpful.

Comment: Unclear : Do you wish to block users from having full access to their home folder? This is not possible. Are you perhaps looking for [SFTPExtensions homeDirectory](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/RELEASE_NOTES-1.3.8rc4)?

Comment: @harrymc I waqnt to jail users to their home folder, with full access to it

Answer (score 0):

Use file permissions to prevent each user's home directory from being world-readable, i.e. change the permissions from 0755 to something like 0710 (with your HTTP server's group still having "execute" access).

Alternatively: enable the [chroot](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html) function, using either `ChrootDirectory` option in OpenSSH, or the `DefaultRoot ~` option in ProFTPd, depending on which software is actually serving SFTP.

Keep in mind that SFTP is not FTP. Although ProFTPd supports both, it only handles FTP by default. If you have interactive SSH access to the server, then it's pretty much guaranteed that SFTP on port 22 is handled by OpenSSH, **not** by ProFTPd.

Comment: Thanks, I already have tried the DefaultRoot ~ option, but it seems did nothing. I know the difference betweem FTP and SFTP, and I everything works fine in the case of all users, BUT if a user tries to connect with their credentials and selects the protocol SFTP instead of FTP, they CAN connect but with full access.
How can I disabled connect via SFTP? I still didnt find.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I found the solution. It have to simply add a `DenyUsers username` directive to the `sshd_config` file.

I found the solution here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266413/how-to-disable-sftp-for-a-user-but-keep-ftp-enabled